# Accepting CTRL-C as input

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have one problem in a Linux script.

```
#!/bin/bash 
x=1;
while [ $x != 0 ]
do
  echo "Type a command:"
   read -r command
   eval "$command"
  if [ "$command" = end ]
   then x=0;
  fi
  if [ "$command" = kill ]
   then echo "To end the program, type the end"
  fi
done
```

And I want to make the same thing with CTRL_C like for kill. When a user types CTRL_C, script will display: To end the program, type the end. But I don't know how to do that.

An assignment is :

Write a script working in a loop, displaying the "Enter command:" message and retrieving a string from the keyboard. If the user types "end", the script should end. In all other cases, he should treat the entered string as a command that should be executed by the shell. If during the work the key  was pressed or an attempt was made to kill the script with the kill command, the script should display the following information: To finish the work write "end"

Comment: Ctrl+C can be handled in a `trap` statement, or you can arrange things so that the Ctrl-C is read as a character by the `read`. Which would you prefer? If this is an assignment , please give us all the details.

Comment: Ignoring your question for the moment, should't the `eval $command` part be *after* the two `if`s? You may also want to take a look at `case` in the Compound Commands section of the man page for `bash`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick 
An assignment is :
Write a script working in a loop, displaying the "Enter command:" message and retrieving a string from the keyboard. If the user types "end", the script should end. In all other cases, he should treat the entered string as a command that should be executed by the shell. If during the work the key <ctrl-c> was pressed or an attempt was made to kill the script with the kill command, the script should display the following information: To finish the work write "end"

Comment: @nohillside Sure, I will consider that.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the text of the assignment from that comment? I think it would make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl-C is "special" when you have terminal emulation because it is caught and results in a signal (SIGINT) to be sent to your script. You have two options:

- You can make your script catch SIGINT and handle it as you wish. This is done with `trap xxx SIGINT` where xxx is a bash function to execute
- You can make the terminal ignore ctrl-c by running `stty intr undef`. You'll most probably have some issues catching ctrl-c though.